# ZF2 - MySQL PDO Connect Error: could not find driver

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, driver

I'm facing this error and there's nothing I found that helped me.

According to `php --ini` command:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php5/cli
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php5/cli/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/05-opcache.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mysql.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
```

The `php -m` command output shows the `PDO` module is loaded.

I found in `/usr/lib/php5/` a folder named `201312206` with all my extensions in there. I tried to modify the `extension_dir = './'` configuration and set to this folder's path but then when I execute the command `php -i | grep eaccelerator`, and error like this is shown:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/201312206/pdo.so' - /usr/lib/php5/201312206/pdo.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

with all the files present in this folder.

To avoid this, I commented the line where it sets the `extention_dir` again.

My ZF2 `local.php` is:

```
return array(
    'db' => array(
        'driver' => 'PDO',
        'dsn' => 'mysql:dbname=rxe;host=localhost;charset=utf8',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '1633',
        'driver_options' => array(
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
        )
    )
);
```

I appreciate.

Comment: Its not clear if the 'unable to load dynamic library' error is the one you mention in your first sentence, or if there is another error occurring.

Comment: Forgive me. The error is `Connect Error: could not find driver`.

Comment: you have adapter related problem which would be tough enough to fix. I would rather recommend you to [read zf2 adapter manual](https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.10/en/zend.db.adapter.html) to start connecting again

Answer (score 0):

Try PdoMysql in 'driver'

```
'db' => array(
      'driver'         => 'PdoMysql',
      'hostname'       => 'localhost',
      'database'       => 'test',
      'username'       => 'root',
      'password'       => '',
       'driver_options' => array(
           PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
       ),
   ),
```